# Cannot change Empathy chat status from Me Menu when using IRC

Tags: empathy, irc, memenu

I use Empathy as chat client for IRC. Since it is the default chat client, I expected that I can update (availability) status from top menu, but it is disabled.

[image: Status disabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have happened to me too a few times. What I did was:

Make sure empathy is actually running (there should be a little arrow in the Messages indicator).

Open Empathy and check to see if it have failed to connect to a im network (msn, google talk etc.).

Usually it's the latter.

Comment: Empathy is running and I'm chatting. I use it for a month now, connected to an IRC channel. Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting just to an IRC channel or other accounts like googletalk, msn, etc.. ?

Comment: Just IRC channel.

Comment: Now I tried to add googletalk and it works with it. So I guess this is a bug?